# ERC20 Token not shown on Ether Scan - Rospten

Tags: solidity, truffle, erc20

I've successfully deployed once my own ERC20 token on Ropsten network with positive result. I can see the ERC20 token contract address associated to those correspondence accounts. But, when I try to change the token name and re-deploy to the ropsten network again, I coudn't see the new token details anymore. Did I miss any steps?
Please see the attached screenshots below.
[image: CToken]
[image: MToken]

> CToken - 0x0225b59b64aa51bd1cbf425896c70999c8c65565
>
> MToken-  0x493d100661632C8e9d28F7144CCF046bA1a2E728

I thought is quite straight forward, I can just see the token on EtherScan upon successfully deployed.

Please advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Etherscan shows your CToken and MToken (when viewing from the token URL).
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/token/0x0225b59b64aa51bd1cbf425896c70999c8c65565
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/token/0x493d100661632C8e9d28F7144CCF046bA1a2E728

It may be that because MToken has no token transactions, Etherscan didn't identify it as an ERC20 token.  I viewed from the token URL and it was picked up.  I also added as a custom token into MetaMask.

If you are not already, you can use OpenZeppelin as the basis to create your tokens.
See the OpenZeppelin documentation for details:
https://docs.openzeppelin.org/v2.3.0/tokens

If you have questions about OpenZeppelin you can also ask in the [community forum](https://forum.zeppelin.solutions/)

Comment: @abcoathup-  You saved my day!

Comment: May I know when I re-deploy the same ERC20 token contract, do I have to give a new name or I can just re-use the same name. In my opinion, it get a new hashed key eventually.

Comment: You can re-deploy the exact same contract and it will have a different public address.

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much.

Comment: Quick one, I just re-deployed the same ERC20 CToken contract to the Ropsten network without changing anything. When I add the new instance of the  CToken to my wallet account, it just doesn't appear. Wondering could it be due to the same token name?

Comment: You didn't specify which wallet you are using. e.g. MetaMask

Comment: @abcoathup-let me try on that.